# Does a Python upgrade make Cython extensions rare?

Tags: python, variables, version, cython, declaration

I wanted to upgrade Python 3.11.4 to 3.11.5 and my same .pyd extensions are not compiling as before. The same code had no issues in version 3.11.4, so I reinstalled the 3.11.4 again, but the problem is still there in all declarations of this type:

```
i:Py_ssize_t=0

Unknown type declaration 'Py_ssize_t' in annotation, ignoring
```

Py_ssize_t is part of Cython. What is happening?

Answer (score -1):

I think it's more likely to be linked to a change in Cython version than a change in Python version.

Specifically for `Py_ssize_t` as an annotation, Cython expects you to use it as a name `cimport`ed from Cython rather than a raw name:

```
cimport cython

#...

i: cython.Py_ssize_t=0
```

I suspect it's just the output of the warning that's been added rather than the underlying behaviour but I could be wrong - there have been fairly significant changes to the handling of annotations in Cython 3.

Comment: Yes you are right! with cython.Py_ssize_t. The thing is that I have to change everything, so I prefer to work with a previos version of cython. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's quite likely that the previous version of Cython is ignoring the annotation but not giving you a warning. You should check that before you decide to use it.